# Images not showing up?

Tags: image, url, webserver

I just launched my website from localhost to a real domain, and now some of the images are not showing up.

I am certain that they are there and that they are linked correctly. I have double and triple checked but for example http://techxpertschico.com/images/random/frustratedflyers.png will not show up and 
http://techxpertschico.com/images/random/check.png will and I can observe that they are in the same folder.

What other things could cause this?

Comment: It's a 404 error but I know the files are there

Comment: Are you sure that the file `frustratedflyers.png` is all lower-case?

Comment: Classic id10t error. Or even better is the pebkac (problem exists between keyboard and chair)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your Web Server is case sensitive.

If you access http://techxpertschico.com/images/random/FrustratedFlyer.png it works, by the way its FrustratedFlyer not Flyers, anyway, if you access your image like this http://techxpertschico.com/images/random/frustratedflyer.png it will not work.

Fix you server case sensitiveness and it will work!

Regards.

P.S: for apache check this out http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/108-how-to-permit-case-insensitive-urls-with-apache/.

Comment: You are the man! Thanks! And actually I have a couple of poorly named files so I think you found one of the extra stragglers haha!